# How to CONCAT a update query in a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a procedure to update a row when a bug gets fixed. Here is what it looks like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE bugFix (
    IN rid_in INT,
    IN fix_details_in VARCHAR (300)
) BEGIN
    SET @resolved_qry = CONCAT('UPDATE _bug_report SET resolved = 1 WHERE rid = ', rid_in);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @resolved_qry;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    UPDATE _bug_report SET fix_details = CONCAT(fix_details, fix_details_in) WHERE rid = CONCAT(rid, rid_in);

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When changing the resolved type to 1:

```
SET @resolved_qry = CONCAT('UPDATE _bug_report SET resolved = 1 WHERE rid = ', rid_in);
PREPARE stmt FROM @resolved_qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

It works fine, however when updating the `fix_details` column to include the details it does not work:

```
UPDATE _bug_report SET fix_details = CONCAT(fix_details, fix_details_in) WHERE rid = CONCAT(rid, rid_in);
```

Here is how I call it:

```
CALL bugFix(1, 'Hey, we fixed it');
```

Any ideas how to do this to use the `fix_details_in` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using dynamic SQL?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE bugFix (
    IN rid_in INT,
    IN fix_details_in VARCHAR (300)
) BEGIN
    UPDATE _bug_report
        SET resolved = 1,
            fix_details = CONCAT(fix_details, fix_details_in)
        WHERE rid = rid_in;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Presumably, "not work" means that `fix_details` is not being updated.  That would be because nothing matches:

```
WHERE rid = CONCAT(rid, rid_in)
```

Given that `rid_in` is an integer, this will always fail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Apologies for previous comment, I saw `)` was missing from `CONCAT()` statement, this information is amazing! I'll accept when I can !